# c++ vector with struct to map?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, stdmap

I have a vector with this struct:

```
struct AB
{
      int id, x, y;
}
```

x and y are coordinates.
The data in the vector looks like this:

1. id 22   x 53.2    y 8.90
2. id 22   x 53.3    y 8.91
3. id 25   x 53.4    y 8.92 ...

You can see that some id's contain more than one coordinate. Therefore, I am looking for a way to save the data in a different form. Which is more suitable to work with the data further. Has anyone a tip?

Comment: You could use a `multimap`.

Comment: *Which is more suitable to work with the data further* What do you mean by *more suitable*?  What do you need to do with the data once you have it?

Comment: For example, I want to calculate the distance from Id 22

Comment: Which id 22? You'll have to explain your goal better, perhaps with more of an example.

Comment: ```map<int, vector<AB>>``` where ```id``` isn't a part of AB struct

Comment: @ Retired Ninja I have geographic data. Id refers to the street name. Logically, a road has several coordinates. Therefore, my id also has several coordinates. In my example which data my vector contains I have the id 22 mentioned.

Comment: @trsm you have 2 id 22's so from which id 22 do you want to calculate the distance from? or are you talking about the distance between all of the points in id 22?

Comment: yes i'm talking about the distance between all of the points in id 22

Comment: Well, every data structure mentioned here will let you do that, the simplest one to use would be the one mentioned by Danyal.  As far as calculating the distance of all the points in the map, you will have to write a function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how do you fill and use the data. If there is one-time load of all the data just at the beginning and then only using the loaded data, it could be actually beneficial to keep the vector, load all the data, sort it once according to the ids and then use the sorted vector - because of the contiguous block which has better locality and thus much better cache behavior (contrary to the ordered or unordered map structures that imply chasing pointers all around the place, which is not very cache friendly). This can also work if the new items are only added rarely. Note that this would have the same big-O as having a balanced tree-based map (if you'll do binary search in the sorted vector), as long as new items do not need to be added after the sorting.

If the new items are added frequently, you can use std::multimap (or unordered which works based on hashes), or map/unordered_map of vectors of points.

The decision which one is better for you should be based on measurements of current speed and the speed after the change (you generally don't want the "improved" version to be slower than the original one).